# Compare all of the fields of a tuple field together in Pig Latin

Tags: apache-pig

What i need to do:
Compare all of the values that i get in a field (coming from a database) with each other, and check whether or not they are all equal.i.e.

```
A = 
(John,18,4.0F)
(Mary,19,3.8F)
(Bill,20,3.9F)
(Joe,18,3.8F)
```

If they are all equal then return value 'true'; else value 'false' . Ideally i would need a DISTINCT function at a field level.

Here column 2 (refered as $1 would yield a true as there are 2 '18' values).

I was thinking of doing a cross join on the bag itself, to be able to compare the values, i.e get something like:

```
 (John, 18, 4.0F, Mary, 19 , ..)
 (Mary, 19, 3.8F, Bill, 20, .. )
```

..

and then be able to compare column 2 and 5 (my $1 and $4) together, which becomes trivial.

but performance will suffer. (and not sure that will work).
Any other ideas?

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: Please provide more detail about what you are trying to do. Sample input and output would be very helpful.

Comment: edited to add example

Comment: So you want to compare adjacent pairs of records, given a particular order?

Answer (score 0):

you can write a Pig UDf and pass all the values to be sorted in the UDF then compare only the adjacent values. It would help if you could explain your usecase even more clearly.